# Using Python AST to get the value from keyword of a context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I have Python source code that is analyzed by an external tool I am writing. The code contains a context manager and I'm trying to get the value (list) of the keyword 'tags' inside the context manager called 'dag'.

```py
from airflow.models import DAG

with DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    tags=['dbt', 'marketing', 'schema', 'data_vis']
) as dag:
    pass
```

The desired output is:

```py
['dbt', 'marketing', 'schema', 'data_vis']
```

I think I can use the `ast` module to parse the file. How can I achieve this?

### Solution

The best solution for my question at the moment was:

```py
# dag.py

from airflow.models import DAG

with DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    tags=['dbt', 'marketing', 'schema', 'data_vis']
) as dag:
    pass
```

```py
# ast_explorer.py

import ast

with open('dag.py', 'r') as f:
    tree = ast.parse(f.read())

for node in tree.body:
    if isinstance(node, ast.With):
        for item in node.items:
            if isinstance(item.context_expr, ast.Call) and item.context_expr.func.id == 'DAG':
                for arg in item.context_expr.keywords:
                    if arg.arg == 'tags':
                        tag_list = [s.s for s in arg.value.elts]

print(tag_list)
>>> ['dbt', 'marketing', 'schema', 'data_vis']
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think you don't understood my problem. Explaining a little bit more, the "dag.py" file where the Airflow DAG are defined will be analized by an external project, so I need to read the "dag.py" and analize the code such as flake8 does.

Comment: We already know ChatGPT doesn't know how to code; don't waste your time using it as "research".

Comment: @chepner I used because I don't want to spend much time learning AST at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse the `ast` object and when you encounter an `ast.withitem` with a corresponding call of an object named `DAG`, iterate over all the keyword objects and save the values associated with keys `tags`:

```
import ast
src = """
from airflow.models import DAG

with DAG(
   dag_id='my_dag',
   tags=['dbt', 'marketing', 'schema', 'data_vis']
) as dag:
    pass
"""
cxt_m = [i for i in ast.walk(ast.parse(src)) if isinstance(i, ast.withitem) 
         and isinstance(i.context_expr, ast.Call) and i.context_expr.func.id == 'DAG']
tags = [ast.literal_eval(ast.unparse(j.value)) for i in cxt_m 
        for j in i.context_expr.keywords if j.arg == 'tags']
print(tags)
```

Output:

```
[['dbt', 'marketing', 'schema', 'data_vis']]
```

Comment: "NameError: name 'd' is not defined." Can you help?

Comment: @MarcosMartins Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Yes, it worked now. Thank you! I marked you asnwer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, I found this way to get the list.

```py
import ast

code = """
with DAG(
    tags=['dbt', 'marketing', 'schema', 'data_vis']
) as dag:
    pass
"""

# parse the code into an abstract syntax tree (AST)
tree = ast.parse(code)

# find all with statements in the AST
with_stmts = [node for node in ast.walk(tree) if isinstance(node, ast.With)]

# loop over the with statements and extract the value of the tags argument
for with_stmt in with_stmts:
    for keyword in with_stmt.items:
        for kw in keyword.context_expr.keywords:
            for elm in kw.value.elts:
                print(elm.value)
```

Here, we are looping over the `keyword.context_expr.keywords` args, there is only one kw arg in this case and its a list, so we just get the list and loop over its elements.

You can verify the name of the kwarg using `kw.arg`

Note: This might not work as intended for multiple kwargs.

Edit: To reconstruct the keyword arguments you can do this:

```py
tree = ast.parse(code)

# Fancy syntax to get the first element of this list, as there is only one with stmt here.
(with_stmt,) = [node for node in ast.walk(tree) if isinstance(node, ast.With)]

kwargs = {
    kwarg.arg: ast.literal_eval(kwarg.value)
    for item in with_stmt.items
    for kwarg in item.context_expr.keywords
}

print(kwargs)
```

Comment: How to get it work with multiple kwargs? I edited the code in the original question.

Comment: For multiple kwargs, you can run `ast.literal_eval` on `kw.value`